# UserDialogs loading does not pop up

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I wonder what I am doing wrong in the following implementation.

I cannot able to see loading dialog, even to opening the `ClassroomViewModel` takes few seconds.

```
public IMvxCommand ClassroomSelectedCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand<ClassroomViewModel>(ClassroomSelected);

private async Task ClassroomSelected(Model obj)
{
   using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading..."))
   {
       try
       {
           ShowViewModel<ClassroomViewModel>(new { Id = obj.Id });
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement your command using async/await? I think that the UI thread is blocked when loading your ViewModel.

MvvmCross has a MvxAsyncCommand, and IMvxNavigationService has async navigation methods

Comment: @SalvadorGuerrero Could you please illustrate with an example?

Comment: @hotspring Are you able to see any other dialogs with Acr.UserDialogs besides this one?

Comment: Yes I can able to see `Acr.Dialogs` beside this one.

Answer (score 2):

You are using async APIs, use an MvxAsynCommand

```
private IMvxAsynCommand _classroomSelectedCommand;
public IMvxAsynCommand ClassroomSelectedCommand =>  _classroomSelectedCommand ?? (_classroomSelectedCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand<ClassroomViewModel>(ClassroomSelectedAsync));

private async Task ClassroomSelectedAsync(Model obj)
{
   using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Loading..."))
   {
       await Task.Delay(300);
       try
       {
           ShowViewModel<ClassroomViewModel>(new { Id = obj.Id });
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: If I remove `await Task.Delay(300);` then it does not show. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why but a possible explanation is that if the await is missing, you are executing the task.delay synchronously on the UI thread and the UI thread gets locked.